# Loop text not getting printed inside html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a webpage in which I want to display the articles headlines that I am fetching from NewYork Time API, I am using nodejs as well, but the problem is that my articles gets printed below the end of html, although it should be printed inside like the "SAMPLE TEXT" is getting printed, is there a way in which I can print it inside?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MNY8.jpg

```
                       <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h3 class="title"><center><b>Chronicle</b></center></h3>
                            </div>
                            <body>
                                <p id="headline">SAMPLE TEXT</p>
                                <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.9/p5.js"></script>
                                <script>
                                var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
                                url += '?' + $.param({
                                    'api-key': "removed",
                                    'q': "Trump"
                                });
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: url,
                                    method: 'GET',
                                }).done(function(result) {
                                    var articles = result.response.docs;
                                    for (var i=0; i<articles.length;i++)
                                    {
                                        document.createElement('div');
                                        document.createElement("H1");
                                        var h = document.createElement("H1");
                                        var t = document.createTextNode(articles[i].headline.main);
                                        h.appendChild(t);
                                        document.body.appendChild(h);
                                    }

                                }).fail(function(err) {
                                    throw err;
                                });
                                </script>


                            </body>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: How many body tags do you have in your page? seeing one in the middle of the div I think there is one outside, the overall body tag of document. Therefore the document.body.appendChild(h); is appending to that Body.

Comment: @techLove No, there are no errors.

Comment: @NawedKhan I have only one body tag, there is only div closing under the code that I already mentioned, this is nearly all the code besides header and closing of divs.

Comment: you should not have div and then body tag. this is not the right structure. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Comment: But I want to print inside a card view, if I do not use that then it will not be printed inside the card that I have. It is also not getting printed now as well but this is due to a completely different reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your articles are being inserted at the end of the page because that is what you are asking javascript to do in your "document.body.appendchild" line. If you want your retrieved articles to go in a specific div or p tag, do something like this:

```
<p id="articles">Articles listed below:</p>
<script>
  var newArticle = document.createElement("div");
  var h = document.createElement("H1");
  h.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Header"));
  newArticle.appendChild(h);
  var t = document.createTextNode("New article text");
  newArticle.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("articles").appendChild(newArticle);
</script>
```

I can't test with your original code using the NYT api but you should be able to see how it's done at least with the code above.

Comment: Everything is working, but just one thing, I also have added a text field, so when the user types and hit submit, the function is called (I have made all the code under script into a function). The problem is that, if a user types "obama" and hit enter, the news gets displayed, but after that if he enters "trump", the news fetched is printed at the end of old news, I just want the old news to clear out, is it possible?

Comment: Thanks, that was achieved by: document.getElementById('articles').innerHTML = '';

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!